# Merge sorting a 2d array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, mergesort

I'm stuck again on trying to make this merge sort work. 
Currently, I have a 2d array with a Unix timecode(fig 1) and merge sorting using (fig 2) I am trying to check the first value in each array i.e array[x][0] and then move the whole array depending on array[x][0] value, however, the merge sort creates duplicates of data and deletes other data  (fig 3) my question is what am I doing wrong? I know it's the merge sort but cant see the fix.

fig 1

```
[[1422403200        100]
 [1462834800        150]
 [1458000000         25]
 [1540681200        150]
 [1498863600        300]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]]
```

fig 2

```
import numpy as np


def sort(data):
    if len(data) > 1:
        Mid = len(data) // 2
        l = data[:Mid]
        r = data[Mid:]
        sort(l)
        sort(r)

        z = 0
        x = 0
        c = 0

        while z < len(l) and x < len(r):
            if l[z][0] < r[x][0]:
                data[c] = l[z]
                z += 1
            else:
                data[c] = r[x]
                x += 1
            c += 1

        while z < len(l):
            data[c] = l[z]
            z += 1
            c += 1

        while x < len(r):
            data[c] = r[x]
            x += 1
            c += 1
        print(data, 'done')
unixdate = [1422403200, 1462834800, 1458000000, 1540681200, 1498863600, 1540771200, 1540771200,1540771200, 1540771200, 1540771200]
price=[100, 150, 25, 150, 300, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
array = np.column_stack((unixdate, price))
sort(array)
print(array, 'sorted')
```

fig 3

```
[[1422403200        100]
 [1458000000         25]
 [1458000000         25]
 [1498863600        300]
 [1498863600        300]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]
 [1540771200        100]]
```

Comment: Please provide *full* code to reproduce the problem.  I tried writing a simple wrapper to demonstrate the problem.  I got the correct output, rather than what you see.

Comment: is it perhaps the way i combined them by using array = np.column_stack((unixdate, price))?

Comment: What is this "system" package?  Your code doesn't have any `import`s -- which means it still fails.

Comment: sorry @Prune forgot to add this is every import i have

Comment: MCVE -- include only the imports needed to run the example.  You still don't have a definition for `system`.

Comment: Never mind; simply removing the package designation got the desired (wrong) results.  I edited your posting to match.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't spot any mistake in your code.

I have tried your code and I can tell that the problem does not happen, at least with regular Python lists: The function doesn't change the number of occurrence of any element in the list.

```
data = [
 [1422403200, 100],
 [1462834800, 150],
 [1458000000,  25],
 [1540681200, 150],
 [1498863600, 300],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100],
]

sort(data)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[[1422403200, 100],
 [1458000000, 25],
 [1462834800, 150],
 [1498863600, 300],
 [1540681200, 150],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100],
 [1540771200, 100]]
```

---

<strike>**Edit**, taking into account the numpy context and the use of `np.column_stack`.</strike>

-I expect what happens there is that `np.column_stack` actually creates a **view** mapping over the two arrays. To get a real array rather than a link to your existing arrays, you should [copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) that array:-

```
array = np.column_stack((unixdate, price)).copy()
```

---

**Edit 2**, taking into account the numpy context

This behavior has actually nothing to do with `np.column_stack`; `np.column_stack` already performs a copy.

The reason your code doesn't work is because slicing behaves differently with numpy than with python. Slicing create a **view** of the array which maps indexes.

The erroneous lines are:

```
l = data[:Mid]
r = data[Mid:]
```

Since `l` and `r` just map to two pieces of the memory held by `data`, they are modified when `data` is. This is why the lines `data[c] = l[z]` and `data[c] = r[x]` overwrite values and create copies when moving values.

If `data` is a numpy array, we want `l` and `r` to be copies of data, not just views. This can be achieved using the [`copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) method.

```
l = data[:Mid]
r = data[Mid:]
if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
    l = l.copy()
    r = r.copy()
```

This way, I tested, the copy works.

---

**Note**

If you wanted to sort the data using python lists rather than numpy arrays, the equivalent of np.column_stack in vanilla python is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
z = zip([10, 20, 30, 40], [100, 200, 300, 400], [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])
z
# <zip at 0x7f6ef80ce8c8>
# `zip` creates an iterator, which is ready to give us our entries.
# Iterators can only be walked once, which is not the case of lists.

list(z)
# [(10, 100, 1000), (20, 200, 2000), (30, 300, 3000), (40, 400, 4000)]
```

The entries are (non-mutable) tuples. If you need the entries to be editable, map list on them:

```
z = zip([10, 20, 30, 40], [100, 200, 300, 400], [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])
li = list(map(list, z))
# [[10, 100, 1000], [20, 200, 2000], [30, 300, 3000], [40, 400, 4000]]
```

To transpose a matrix, use `zip(*matrix)`:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    return list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))

transpose(l)
# [[10, 20, 30, 40], [100, 200, 300, 400], [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]]
```

You can also sort a python list `li` using `li.sort()`, or sort any iterator (lists are iterators), using `sorted(li)`.

Here, I would use (tested):

```
sorted(zip(unixdate, price))
```

Comment: Don't *guess* -- until you know you have an solution, you should be commenting, not posting an answer.  I tried your `copy`, and still get the same (wrong) output.